# PHP If-Else Stack seems convoluted

Tags: php, if-statement

I am using PHP to layout a navigation menu and display content according to the URL.

I have reached the IF-ELSE stack that determines what content to show (by loading the necessary classes and/or methods). But there has to be a better way of writing this.. any suggestions?

*BreadCrumbs::getCrumb()* is a static method used to retrieve an element saved from the URL based on the index value (URI Request, split by '/', then saved in array).

...*(ArrayHelp::recValueSearch(BreadCrumbs::getCrumb(2), Config::getNavPrimary())* checks the URI element against the array containing the navigation list from the Config class.

*BreadCrumbs::setEmptyCrumb(1, "home")* runs a method which sets a default value if the value is either not present or not valid (in the nav list array)

```
<?php
// set bread crumbs
BreadCrumbs::setCrumbs($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
BreadCrumbs::setEmptyCrumb(1, "home");
BreadCrumbs::setEmptyCrumb(2, "all");



if (BreadCrumbs::getCrumb(1) == 'about') {
    echo 'This is the <b>About</b> Page';
}
else if (BreadCrumbs::getCrumb(1) == 'contact') {
    echo 'This is the <b>Contact</b> Page';
}
else if (BreadCrumbs::getCrumb(1) == 'search') {
    echo 'This is the <b>Search</b> Page';
}
else if (BreadCrumbs::getCrumb(1) == 'home') {
    if (BreadCrumbs::getCrumb(2) == 'all') {
        echo 'This is the <b>Home</b> Page';
    }
    else if (ArrayHelp::recValueSearch(BreadCrumbs::getCrumb(2), Config::getNavSecondary())) {
        echo 'This is the list page for category: <b>' . BreadCrumbs::getCrumb(1) . '</b> and the country filter is: <b>'. BreadCrumbs::getCrumb(2) . '</b>';
    }
    else {
        echo 'change filter value and go to the <b>home</b> page';
    }
}
else if (ArrayHelp::recValueSearch(BreadCrumbs::getCrumb(1), Config::getNavPrimary())) {
    if (BreadCrumbs::getCrumb(2) == 'all') {
        echo 'This is the list page for category: <b>' . BreadCrumbs::getCrumb(1) . '</b> and the country filter is <b>all countries</b>';
    }
    else if (ArrayHelp::recValueSearch(BreadCrumbs::getCrumb(2), Config::getNavSecondary())) {
        echo 'This is the list page for category: <b>' . BreadCrumbs::getCrumb(1) . '</b> and the country filter is: <b>'. BreadCrumbs::getCrumb(2) . '</b>';
    }
    else {
        echo 'change filter value to all and go to category: <b>' . BreadCrumbs::getCrumb(1) . '</b>';
    }
}
else {
    echo 'redirect page to home/all';
}

?>
```

EDIT: Changed to Switch Statement as below, a little better..

```
    <?php
    $array_helper = new ArrayHelp;
    $valid_primary = $array_helper->recValueReturn(BreadCrumbs::getCrumb(1), Config::getNavPrimary());
    $valid_secondary = $array_helper->recValueReturn(BreadCrumbs::getCrumb(2), Config::getNavSecondary());
    switch (BreadCrumbs::getCrumb(1)) {
        case 'about' :
        case 'contact' :
        case 'search' :
            echo 'This is the <b>' . BreadCrumbs::getCrumb(1) . '</b> Page';
            break;
        case 'home' :
            switch (BreadCrumbs::getCrumb(2)) {
                case 'all' :
                    echo 'This is the <b>Home</b> Page';
                    break;
                case ($valid_secondary[1]) : 
                    echo 'This is the list page for category: <b>' . BreadCrumbs::getCrumb(1) . '</b> and the country filter is: <b>'. BreadCrumbs::getCrumb(2) . '</b>';
                    break;
                default:
                    echo 'change filter value and go to the <b>' . BreadCrumbs::getCrumb(1) . '</b> page';
                    break;
            }
            break;
        case ($valid_primary[1]) :
            switch (BreadCrumbs::getCrumb(2)) {
                case ($valid_secondary[1]) : 
                    echo 'This is the list page for category: <b>' . BreadCrumbs::getCrumb(1) . '</b> and the country filter is: <b>'. BreadCrumbs::getCrumb(2) . '</b>';
                    break;
                default:
                    echo 'change filter value and go to the <b>' . BreadCrumbs::getCrumb(1) . '</b> page';
                    break;
            }
            break;
        default:
            echo 'redirect page to home/all';
            break;
    }
?>
```

Comment: Removed [OOP], because it has nothing to do with OOP.

Comment: Static-*everything* is not OOP.  It's half-assed namespacing.  Please [read up on what makes PHP5 OOP actually OOP](http://php.net/language.oop5).

Comment: Not Everything is Static. Just the Config and the Breadcrumbs. Thought that would be best. The rest of what I'm working on are not static.. Would you like to explain a little more?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your example code shows your complete requirements some of it could be greatly simplified by just using the actual string returned by `getCrumb`:

```
  $crumb = ucfirst(BreadCrumbs::getCrumb(1));
  switch($crumb){

     case 'home': case 'foobar': # etc, etc
        echo "This is the <b>$crumb</b> Page";
        break; # or add some extra logic
     default:
        # handle invalid crumbs here
        break;
  }
```

([`ucfirst`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ucfirst.php) is used to make the first character of the string uppercase.)

Comment: I have to make sure the breadcrumb is valid, IE inside the array which holds the list of nav elements.

Comment: I added a switch statement to show how you could do some simple validation. Based on your example, you could put `'about'`,`'contact'` and `'search'` all in one case, deal with `'home'` in another, and deal with invalid crumbs in a third.

Comment: That's exactly what I was hoping for.. Clear up the confusion and make it tighter. Thanks! (and thanks for not insulting my OOP attempts like the guys above)

Comment: No problem - try not to take things like that too personally and use it as an opportunity to learn instead. Happy holidays!

Answer (score 5):

Yes, a switch statement is somewhat cleaner

```
switch(BreadCrumbs::getCrumb(1)) {

   case 'about':
     echo 'This is the <b>About</b> Page';
     break;  

   case 'contact':
     echo 'This is the <b>Contact</b> Page';
     break;

   case 'search':
     echo 'This is the <b>Search</b> Page';
     break;


   // ....

   default: 
     // Default behavior
      break;
}
```

The next step would be and take each of your page printouts and place it either in its own function or externalize the html into template files.

Comment: All of those could be combined into one switch case which does `echo "This is the <b>" . ucwords(BreadCrumbs::getCrumb(1)) . "</b> Page";`

Comment: I'd have to use switch statements within switch statements to consider both navs.. still cleaner?